# PostgresSQL: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

When trying select columns from table A with select subquery that takes id column from table B I get an error

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT 
    id, column_1, column_2, column_3, 
    (SELECT id FROM table_b AS b 
     WHERE b.column_1 = table_a.column_1 
       AND b.column_2 = table_a.column_2 
       AND b.column_3 = table_a.column_3) as b_id 
FROM 
    table_a;
```

Comment: Add `LIMIT 1` to your subquery, and most likely an ORDER BY as well, or change the entire query.

Comment: The question is: what do you want to achieve? Which of the possible answers (qualifying rows) do you want? Any, all, a specific one?

Comment: `LIMIT 1` works, Thanks!!

Comment: It ran but was the result correct? As others have mentioned with out some qualifications to the query  you are essentially rolling the dice on each run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting multiple rows from a subquery that's returning multiple rows, you need a way to pick a winner. The easiest and most portable way is to aggregate, often using `MAX()`:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    column_1,
    column_2,
    column_3, 
    (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_b AS b 
     WHERE b.column_1 = table_a.column_1 
       AND b.column_2 = table_a.column_2 
       AND b.column_3 = table_a.column_3) as b_id 
FROM table_a
```

You can use `MIN()` too or even `AVG()` for non-id numeric values - whichever suits for your context.